# Regex to turn query string into slashes and values

Tags: php, regex

What would be the regex in PHP for turning:

```
?take=2&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=2&comment=the%20comment
```

Into:

```
/2/0/1/2/the%20comment
```

---

Thanks, I did the following:

```
$qPos = strpos($url, '?') ;

        $queryString = substr($url, $qPos+1) ;

        parse_str($queryString, $params) ;
        foreach($params as $param) {
            $pString .= '/'.$param ; 
        }
        $url = substr($url, 0, $qPos).$pString ; 
        echo $url ;
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and build a new string.

Comment: @Felix Kling +1 Thanks, I didn't know about that function.

Comment: Alternative you can do `$pString = '/' . implode('/', $params)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the $_GET variable?
Eg:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$skip = $GET['skip'];
$str = $name . " " . $skip etc etc
```

Comment: No, due to the way I have made my router.